# VS Code Debug Mode Not Automatically Opening Browser for ASP.NET Core Application on Apple M1 Mac

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, debugging, browser

I'm developing a web application using ASP.NET Core 7.0 on an Apple M1 Mac with Visual Studio Code as my IDE.

When I run the command `dotnet run --launch-profile https`, everything works as expected. I can open my application by manually entering `https://localhost:7273/swagger` into my browser.

However, when I try to debug my application in VS Code by pressing F5, the debugger starts and the application runs, but the browser does not automatically open as expected. After pressing F5, the output message is as follows:

```
Running task: dotnet build /path/to/my/project/TreeForSuccess.sln /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary 

MSBuild version 17.6.8+c70978d4d for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  TreeForSuccess -> /path/to/my/project/bin/Debug/net7.0/TreeForSuccess.dll
Task to be reenabled. Press any key to close.
```

(Note: `/path/to/my/project` is a placeholder for the actual path to my project on my local machine.)

However, the debug mode ends immediately afterwards.

In my `launch.json`, I have the `serverReadyAction` configured as follows:

```json
"serverReadyAction": {
    "action": "openExternally",
    "pattern": "^\s*Now listening on:\s+(https?://\S+)"
}
```

I expected VS Code to open a new browser window with the URL `https://localhost:7273/swagger` when I start debugging, but this does not happen.

Has anyone else encountered this issue, or does anyone have any insights on what could be causing this and how to resolve it?

Thank you.

I pressed F5 in VS Code to debug my ASP.NET Core 7.0 web application. I expected VS Code to automatically open a new browser window and navigate to https://localhost:7273/swagger. However, while the debugger started and the application ran, the browser did not open automatically.